# very strange duplicate symbol in xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, clang

Projet SampleAppRef reference project B. Project B 's target is libyodo1SDK_SNS-AD-ALS-GMG.a .

When I build project SampleAppRef, It has this error, it tells me duplicate symbol:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AdViewAdapterDomobImpl in /Users/dengjian/project/SDK_iOS/trunk/Yodo1SDK/Prj/yodo1SDK/build-yodo1SDK_SNS-AD-ALS-GMG/Release-iphonesimulator/libyodo1SDK_SNS-AD-ALS-GMG.a(AdViewAdapterDoMob.o) and /Users/dengjian/project/SDK_iOS/trunk/Yodo1SDK/Prj/yodo1SDK/build-yodo1SDK_SNS-AD-ALS-GMG/Release-iphonesimulator/libyodo1SDK_SNS-AD-ALS-GMG.a(AdViewAdapterDoMob.o) for architecture i386
```

and The ld command is:

```
Ld build-SampleAppRef/Release-iphonesimulator/SampleApp.app/SampleApp normal i386
cd /Users/dengjian/project/SDK_iOS/trunk/Yodo1SDKSample/SampleApp
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/dengjian/project/SDK_iOS/trunk/Yodo1SDKSample/SampleApp/build-SampleAppRef/Release-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dengjian/project/SDK_iOS/trunk/Yodo1SDKSample/SampleApp/build-SampleAppRef/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/dengjian/project/SDK_iOS/trunk/Yodo1SDKSample/SampleApp/build-SampleAppRef/SampleAppRef.build/Release-iphonesimulator/SampleAppRef.build/Objects-normal/i386/SampleApp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -all_load -lxml2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40200 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework MessageUI -framework MediaPlayer -framework MapKit -framework ImageIO -framework iAd -framework EventKit -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreLocation -framework CFNetwork -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -lz -lstdc++ -lsqlite3 -liconv -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics /Users/dengjian/project/SDK_iOS/trunk/Yodo1SDK/Prj/yodo1SDK/build-yodo1SDK_SNS-AD-ALS-GMG/Release-iphonesimulator/libyodo1SDK_SNS-AD-ALS-GMG.a -o /Users/dengjian/project/SDK_iOS/trunk/Yodo1SDKSample/SampleApp/build-SampleAppRef/Release-iphonesimulator/SampleApp.app/SampleApp
```

1. when I remove the reference project B, and build the project B single. Then add the yodo1SDK_SNS-AD-ALS-GMG.a to project SampleAppRef, it works well!
2. When I remove the duplicate file AdViewAdapterDoMob.h and AdViewAdapterDoMob.m from project project B, It works well too! and I can runs and call the code of AdViewAdapterDoMob.m .

project SampleAppRef self doesn't has any code of "AdViewAdapterDomobImpl". So why it has dumplcate symbol?

Can anybody give me some hints?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear log then press stop. after that clear the log again and quit xcode. restart mac and try again. See if that works.